# Setting up JSDOM navigator.serviceWorker for unit testing service workers

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js, service-worker, jsdom

I'm looking for a way to set up navigator.serviceWorker to unit test my service worker. My current JSDOM setup looks like this:

```
import { JSDOM } from 'jsdom';

const dom = new JSDOM('<!DOCTYPE html><html><head></head><body></body></html>');

global.window = dom.window;
global.document = dom.window.document;

Object.keys(global.window).forEach(property => {
  if (typeof global[property] === 'undefined') {
    global[property] = global.window[property];
  }
});

global.navigator = {
  userAgent: 'node.js'
};
```

I've already tried commenting out `global.navigator = ...` for `global.navigator = global.window.navigator`. However, the following `console.log(global.navigator.serviceWorker)` and `console.log(navigator.serviceWorker)` both return `undefined` in my unit test:

```
describe('Service Worker', () => {
  it('should register a service worker and cache files on install', () => {
    console.log(navigator.serviceWorker); // undefined
    // navigator.serviceWorker.register() // not used yet since undefined
  });
});
```

Answer (score 10):

Use `Object.defineProperty` method to create a new `serviceWorker` property:

```
Object.defineProperty(global.navigator, 'serviceWorker', {
  value: {
    register: jest.fn() // Choose your favourite mocking library
  }
});
```

Defining `register` method as a mock function, will allow you to spy the calls made to that function and also return a promise that can be resolve or reject.

```
import sw from './service-worker';

describe('Service worker registration', () => {
  it('call navigator.serviceWorker.register with the right URL', () => {
    expect(navigator.serviceWorker.register).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/service-worker.js');
  });
});
```